# Better way to check dictionary for alternative keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm parsing a dictionary which may have the value I want under 4 possible keys (I have no control over the dictionary).

The key could be `"value"` `"_value"` `"amount"` or `"_amount"`

Currently my only idea is

```
try:
    val = myDict["value"]
except KeyError:
    try:
        val = myDict["_value"]
    except KeyError:
        try:
            val = myDict["amount"]
        except KeyError:
            val = myDict["_amount"]
```

But this is making me feel sick just looking at it. Any better ideas?

Comment: The last one has no `try`. Does that mean one of the four always exists?

Comment: why don't you use `get`?

Comment: Does the check always need to be in that order? Because, you can do a `.get(key)` for all those keys and just use whichever has a value and not `None`. Also, will it happen that the value can be in more than 1 key (i.e. the dict has both `"value"` and `"_value"`), and if so, which do you pick?

Comment: @nocomment no, I want the KeyError to be raised if none of the four exists.

Comment: @diggusbickus @Gino-Mempin good idea, maybe something like ```val = myDict.get("value", myDict.get("_value", myDict.get("amount", myDict.get("_amount", None))))``` and then do something if the returned value is None.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question with what I ended up going with.

I decided to just write a function to try multiple keys as is it more readable than the nested `.get()` calls.

```
def tryMultipleKeys(myDict, keysToCheck):
    val = None
    for k in keysToCheck:
        val = myDict.get(k)
        if val is not None:
            break
    else:
        raise KeyError(f"None of the keys ({keysToCheck}) were found in {myDict}")
    return val
```

Comment: better use `if k in myDict: return myDict[key]`

Answer (score 1):

```
   def tryMultipleKeys(myDict, keysToCheck):
     for key in keysToCheck : 
        if key in myDict :
           return myDict[key]
     return None
```

Answer (score -1):

Pseudo code(if you just want to check if value is present):

1. get the values with values = myDict.values()
2. check if value is in values
3. now implement your logic

Python Code:

```
values = myDict.values()
if value in values:
   #your logic
```

Pseudo code(if you just want to get key if value is present):

1. get keys and values using keys= myDict.keys() and values
2. get index of value
3. key = myDict['index_of_value']

Python code:

```
keys = myDict.keys()
values = myDict.values()
if value in values:
   index_of_value = values.index(value)
   key = keys[index_of_value]
```